# How to write value to specified coordinate in vertex shader with gl_position?

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader

I just want to write the input points to the specified coordinate in vertex shader for some gpgpu operations.

Details :
I have 5 points, and there's some algorithm in vertex shader. 
Then I want to write the points_result[0] to the texture(render to texture) which coordinate is (1,0) so that I can use glReadPixels from the result texture, (or something like (0.5,0.5)for the first point_result, (1.5,0.5) for the second point_result. etc).

**Namely, How to mapping gl_position to the coordinate of the rendered texture result?**

--It seems that something is wrong.
I draw 4 points here:
(1, 3, 1)
(3, 1, 2)
(2, 8, 3)
(4, 3, 5)

```
    #version 330
    layout (location = 0) in vec3 inPosition;
    flat out vec4 tofrag; 
    void main()
    {
        vec2 cord = vec2(-1+ (gl_VertexID)*2.0/6, 0);
        gl_Position = vec4(cord, 0, 1.0);
        tofrag = vec4(inPosition.xyz, -1); 

    }
```

the fragment shader, I just output the tofrag.

```
    #version 330
    out vec4 outputColor;
    flat in vec4 tofrag;

    void main()
    {
        outputColor = tofrag;
    }
```

When I read the window-size(6*1) pixels, Here shows the result.

```
0: (1.00,1.00,1.00,-1.00)
1: (3.00,2.00,2.00,-1.00)
2: (2.00,3.00,3.00,-1.00)
3: (4.00,5.00,5.00,-1.00)
4: (0.00,0.00,0.00,1.00)
5: (0.00,0.00,0.00,1.00)
```

It seems that, this shader can only get the (x,z,z)coordinate, maybe it is cause of interpolation ,but how to avoid it?

Comment: Explain what exactly it is you're trying to do. Can you post your shader(s)?

Comment: Which gl version do you target? GL 3.3, 4.3, 4.4...?

Comment: It seem that I find the way to solve it. It always use (-1,-1) (1,1) to mapping the screen coordinate.  I am using GL3.3 .

Comment: What is the 'flat' in your variable definitions? That looks wrong to me.
Are your shaders building? are you checking them that they are?